# MacOS Push Notification does'nt have "Open" button

Tags: ios, macos, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement push notification for MacOS system. I've created production certificate, appId, provision profile, signed my app and now I can retrieve push notification on my MacOS. But after click on it - nothing happens. And there are only "close" button there. For example another app has "Open" button on alert or "Reply". 
Here is the screen shot of alert:

[image]

Here is the code of registration and handling push notification:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
        NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach{ window in
             window.isOpaque = false
             window.backgroundColor = NSColor.fromRGB(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 70)
        }

    }

    func application(_ application: NSApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        notificationService?.handleToken(deviceToken: deviceToken)
    }

    func application(_ application: NSApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        notificationService?.handlePushRegistrationFailed(error:error)
    }

    func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any]) {
        notificationService?.didReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo:userInfo)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to user can see my app after click push notification alert.

Comment: Have you read the section "Assigning Custom Actions to a Remote Notification" at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: Docs says that actionable notifications are supported only on iOS and watchOS.